# How to point single page with dynamic url in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have the below use case.

- I have a list of `$states: ['Alaska, 'Virginia', 'California']` so once the user type state in the URL `ex:  xyz.com/virgina`  then after extracting the state from the URL I have to point to one page only that I have created from WordPress Admin default page URL is `xyz.com/page-1`

Thanks In Advance

I have tried with `wp_redirect(`) function but it's redirecting to specific page  and changing the URL as well but URL should not change.